# Pantheios set display level in C++

Tags: c++, logging, pantheios, log-level

I'm using Pantheios library for logging. I have:

```
pantheios::log(pantheios::debug, "I'm debug");
pantheios::log(pantheios::informational, "Some info");
```

Which outputs:

```
[MyApplication, Jun 14 15:45:26.549; Debug] : I'm debug
[MyApplication.1, Jun 14 15:45:26.549; Informational] : Some info
```

But I want to choose between display info and debug:

```
 set_level(pantheios::informational) //what should this be ?
 pantheios::log(pantheios::debug, "I'm debug");
 pantheios::log(pantheios::informational, "Some info");
```

Which outputs:

```
[MyApplication.1, Jun 14 15:45:26.549; Informational] : Some info
```

Comment: http://dinhngocson.blogspot.com/2010/11/pantheios-logging-library-basic.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "right" way to actually filter log levels is to customize
the logger front-end and override `pantheios::pantheios_fe_isSevereityLogged()`, something along these lines:

```
namespace
{
    static int s_log_level = pantheios::debug;
}

PANTHEIOS_CALL(int) pantheios_fe_isSeverityLogged(void *token,
    int severity, int backEndId)
{
    return severity <= s_log_level;
}
```

You should refer to [this](http://www.pantheios.org/doc/html-old/group__group____frontend.html#g0d1cad3ff6ae403cc318f15f063e325e) and [this example](http://www.pantheios.org/doc/html-old/cpp_2example__cpp__custom__fe_2example__cpp__custom__fe_8cpp-example.html#a59) for more information.

Comment: Gave me multiple definition error with using of pantheios.1.fe.simple.gcc46 (also with pantheios.1.fe.all.gcc46)

Comment: My code was meant only to give the general idea, not a copy-paste solution. You should check out [the example](http://www.pantheios.org/doc/html-old/cpp_2example__cpp__custom__fe_2example__cpp__custom__fe_8cpp-example.html#a59) I've referred you to, it's much more detailed and comprehensive. Also, just from looking at the code, I see that you forgot to `#include <pantheios/frontend.h>`...

Comment: Yes :) I removed pantheios.1.fe.all.gcc46 from my linked libraries, took source code fe.all.c from pantheios, placed it to my project and changed function isSeverityLogged. Works great, thanks :)